# incorrect structure memory allocation exit code

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm a beginner to C, and I just had some trouble with what I suspect to be memory allocation. I've got a singly LL where I have a function that removes a node from the head.

```
void removelist(LIST* list){
    // underflow condition
    if (list-> head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    static NODE* printer;

    if(printer==NULL){
        (list->count)--;
        printer = list->head;
        list->head = (list->head)->next;
        (((NODEDATA*)(printer->dataPtr))->pages) = (((NODEDATA*)(printer->dataPtr))->pages) - PAGEPERMINUTE; //pageperminute is just a preprocessor def
        printf(" Print Job Completed - Document Number: %d - Cycle Count: %d",
               ((NODEDATA*)((list-> head)->dataPtr))->docnum, ((NODEDATA*)((list-> head)->dataPtr))->cycles);
        if(((NODEDATA*)(printer)->dataPtr)->pages <=0){
            free(printer);
        }

    }
}
```

When I'm executing the program, it keeps outputting nothing at all and exiting with a random exit code: "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". Through deleting line by line of some function calls in my main, I traced the issue to this line in the removelist function:

```
(((NODEDATA*)(printer->dataPtr))->pages) = (((NODEDATA*)(printer->dataPtr))->pages) - PAGEPERMINUTE;
```

How does this go wrong? For some context, here are the 3 structs I created and the function to initialize the node:

```
typedef struct node{
    void* dataPtr;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct{
    int docnum;
    int priority;
    int pages;
    int cycles;
}NODEDATA;

typedef struct{
    NODE* head;
    int count;
}LIST;

...

NODE* createNode (){
    NODE* nodePtr = malloc (sizeof (NODE));
    nodePtr->next = NULL;
    int Pages = rand() % MAXPAGES;
    int Priority;
    int prioritychance = rand() % 10;

    NODEDATA* data = malloc(sizeof (NODEDATA));
    (nodePtr->dataPtr) = data;

    if(prioritychance ==0){
        Priority = 1;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->pages=Pages;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->priority = Priority;
    }
    else if (prioritychance ==1 || prioritychance==2){
        Priority = 3;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->pages=Pages;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->priority = Priority;
    }
    else{
        Priority = 2;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->pages=Pages;
        ((NODEDATA*)(nodePtr->dataPtr))->priority = Priority;
    }

    return nodePtr;
}
```

Because of the odd exit code I suspect it has something to do with incorrect memory allocation, but I'm not sure. I allocated memory for the nodePtr and the associated data. Did I allocate incorrectly?

Comment: @Gerhardh Would it be initialized to NULL because it's static?

Comment: Not causing this error but you should also do some `free(printer->dataPtr)` before `free(printer)`

Comment: Sorry. I missed the `static`. You are right. But then this whole thing is only executed once.

Comment: and on any subsequent 'first node' removal, `printer` isn't `NULL`.

Comment: What is `removeList` supposed to do? `printer` is static but after first time calling this function, it will not be `NULL` and the function will not do anything. Then maybe the pointer is passed to `free` but not set to `NULL` ... Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gerhardh Basically removelist is supposed to remove the first node from the LL and send it to the "printer", which is the printer pointer. I made printer static so that every time I want to send the first node to the "printer", I gotta check if the printer pointer still points to a node that hasn't been cleared from the last time removelist was called (that's why I check if printer ==NULL). The line that I suspect is wrong is used to update the value of pages.

Comment: There are multiple flaws in that approach: 1) After first call the pointer is not `NULL` and the whole `if` block is skipped. 2) If you fix that condition, you might return earlier from that function because you remove the pointer from the list when you enter the first time. On later calls `list->head == NULL` may already be true while you are still working with the old pointer. 3) After freeing `printer`  you should set it to `NULL` to prevent SEGFAULT on next call.

Comment: That said, this is not causing your isse. Without a MCVE we cannot tell what you do. Running your code in a debugger should show you where it crashes and if that is in the line you suspect.